# What version of LESS is Play Framework 2.1 using?

Tags: playframework-2.0, less

I have a downloaded "less" folder from [WrapBootstrap](https://wrapbootstrap.com/theme/ace-responsive-admin-template-WB0B30DGR)

When I run:

```
lessc ace.less ace.css
```

It works:

But when I compile it inside /assets/less/ace.less, I get a compilation error that is not too helpful:

[image]

1. What Version is LESSC in Play?
2. I've excluded all the libraries except ace.less like the documentation suggested.

Comment: By default, Play uses Less.js with Rhino, and not lessc.

Answer (score 2):

Play 2.1.2 uses LESS 1.3.1, as [can be seen in the code for its `LessCompiler` class](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/2.1.2/framework/src/sbt-plugin/src/main/scala/less/LessCompiler.scala#L9):

```
  val lessScript = "less-1.3.1.js"
```

Starting from [version 2.2.0-M1](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/2.2.0-M1/framework/src/sbt-plugin/src/main/scala/less/LessCompiler.scala), LESS 1.3.3 is used.

Answer (score 0):

This is dependent upon the version of the sbt plugin you're using.

If you look in your project's `plugins.sbt` file, the version of that is visible on the line which looks like this;

```
addSbtPlugin("play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.1.2")
```

At the time of writing, the versions compatible with Play 2.1.x include less 1.3.1. Less 1.3.3 is only included in Play 2.2.0 beta versions, and in the current git version.

You can find out which version is included by navigating [the repository](http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/play/sbt-plugin/) to find the jar file for a particular version of the sbt-plugin, and extracting its jar file.